# Why pass textInput content to string into ArrayList

Tags: android, string, android-textinputlayout, textedit

I want pass values from a form making with TextInputLayout but Android Studio detects my content as INT. 
I put the complete class of my activity as well as the view in .xml to determine the problem

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.prosegma.rso.R;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class AccionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    private Context activity;
    private String[]header={"Campo","Respuesta"};
    private String shortText="RSO PROSEGMA";
    private String longText="Eliminamos Riesgos Sumamos Valor";
    private AccionPdf accionPdf;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accion);


        Button btnCamera1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnCamera1);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.reporte1);
        btnCamera1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });


        Date date = new Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);

        accionPdf=new AccionPdf(getApplicationContext());
        accionPdf.openDocument();
        accionPdf.addMetaData("Reporte","Acción Insegura","www.prosegma.com");
        accionPdf.addTitle("Reporte Acción Insegura","RSO Prosegma"," " +timeStamp);
        accionPdf.addParagraph(shortText);
        accionPdf.addParagraph(longText);
        accionPdf.createTable(header,getClients());
        accionPdf.closeDocument();
    }

    TextInputEditText Nreport = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.nReporta);



    private ArrayList<String[]>getClients(){
        ArrayList<String[]>rows=new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(new String[]{"Nombre de quien reporta", Nreport });
        rows.add(new String[]{"Nombre del trabajador","No"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"Empresa contratista","ju"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"Medidas Necesarias","hu"});
        return rows;
    }


    public void pdfAccion(View view)
    {
accionPdf.verReporteAccion();
    }

    public void enviarA(View view) {

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "receiver_email_address");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email body");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pdfFileName"));
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        email.setType("application/pdf");
        email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getActivity().startActivity(email);
    }

    public Context getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

I update the publication with the activity, I have tried to change the InputTextLayout by EditText but the situation is the same, it throws me an incompatibility error.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar"/>

   <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/reportes0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reportes1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10"
            >



            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reporte1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnCamera1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="64sp"
                android:layout_width="64sp"
                android:background="@drawable/camera"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextBlack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/nReporta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint="NOMBRE DE QUIEN REPORTA"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextBlack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/nTrabajador"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="NOMBRE DEL TRABAJADOR"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextBlack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/eContratista"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="EMPRESA CONTRATISTA"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextBlack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/aMedidas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:hint="ACCIÓN, MEDIDAS CORRECTIVAS INMEDIATAS"
                    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextBlack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                >




            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkAccidente"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ACCIDENTE" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkImpacto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="IMPACTO AMBIENTAL" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkEnfermedad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENFERMEDAR PROFESIONAL" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkReincidente"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="REINCIDENTE" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkSancion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="¿APLICA SANCIÓN?"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/guardarAccion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="GUARDAR REPORTE"
                android:theme="@style/RaisedButtonDark"
                android:onClick="pdfAccion"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextInputEditText Nreport = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.nReporta);
```

this line is outside OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method. Thats why it throws null. It should be like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextInputEditText Nreport;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //  Button btnCamera1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnCamera1);
   // imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.reporte1);



    Date date = new Date();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
     Nreport = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.nReporta);
   getClients();
}





private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){
    ArrayList<String[]>rows=new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(new String[]{"Nombre de quien reporta", Nreport.getText().toString() }); // get text like this
    rows.add(new String[]{"Nombre del trabajador","No"});
    rows.add(new String[]{"Empresa contratista","ju"});
    rows.add(new String[]{"Medidas Necesarias","hu"});
    return rows;
}
```